# How can I find the dependencies of a multiple objects in sql databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

`sp_depends` will provide information for all dependent objects on a particular objects

But it is working for only single object , giving information about single object.

I want the information about multiple object,

> How can I achieve it using sp_depend or any other way is there?

Comment: Examine [Find Dependent Objects](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dmvs/find-dependent-objects) article.

Comment: Thanks very much @HamletHakobyan
how can I use this for multiple objects at a same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`.  This how you get the list of all the dependencies.

Here is an example of how I use it:

```
 select sed.referenced_entity_name, sed.referenced_database_name,
        OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) as ObjectName
 from sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
```

Comment: I want dependencies for many prameters at a same time , i mean to say sp_depend (object1....n) can i use something like this?

Comment: Did you run the query?  It returns all dependencies.  You can then get filter it using a `where` clause.

Comment: I did it it is giving me for one object perfectly .. my question is how can i use it for multiple object s at the same time ?